# If/else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I've just started java couple of days ago. Im currently following this 'course' http://programmingbydoing.com . Havent had encountered any problems yet but now im stuck at task 32.

heres my code so far (always getting Squirrel instead of moose as output):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class TwoQuestion32 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean animal, vegetable, mineral, smallerthan;

    String whatIsIt, biggerThan;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Hello and welcome, i've got 2 questions for you!");
    System.out.println("Think of an object and i'll try to guess it");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Question 1) Is it an animal, vegetable or mineral?");
    System.out.print(">");
    whatIsIt = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (whatIsIt == "animal")
            animal = true;
            if (whatIsIt == "vegetable")
            vegetable = true;
            if (whatIsIt == "mineral")
            mineral = true;


    System.out.println("Question 2) Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
    System.out.print(">");
        biggerThan = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (biggerThan == "yes")
            smallerthan = false;
            if (biggerThan == "no"){
            smallerthan = true;}


            System.out.print("My guess is that you are thinking of a ");
        if (animal = true){
            if (smallerthan = true)
                System.out.println("squirrel");
        }else { 
                System.out.println("moose");}
}   
}
```

Thanks in advance! Would also love to hear tips how to put up the code in smarter ways. Be friendly, keep in mind i've just started!

Edit: Okay I took another approach. My first attempt was really strange. Thanks for the help!

Heres the working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Questions32 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    String whatIsIt, whatIsIt2;
    String animal = "animal";
    String mineral = "mineral";
    String vegetable = "vegetable";
    String bigger = "yes";
    String smaller = "no";


    System.out.println("Hello and welcome, i've got 2 questions for you!");
    System.out.println("Think of an object and i'll try to guess it");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Question 1) Is it an animal, vegetable or mineral?");
    System.out.print(">");
    whatIsIt = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Question 2) Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
    System.out.print(">");
        whatIsIt2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (whatIsIt.equalsIgnoreCase(animal)){
        if (whatIsIt2.equalsIgnoreCase(bigger)){
            System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a moose");
        }else{ System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a squirrel");
        }
    }

    if (whatIsIt.equalsIgnoreCase(vegetable)){
        if (whatIsIt2.equalsIgnoreCase(bigger)){
            System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a melon");
        }else{ System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a carrot");
        }
    }

    if (whatIsIt.equalsIgnoreCase(mineral)){
        if (whatIsIt2.equalsIgnoreCase(bigger)){
            System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a Camaro");
        }else{ System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a paper clip");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("I would ask you if I'm right, but I dont actually care.");

    }


}
```

Comment: Don't compare Strings with `==` or `!=`. Understand that this compares *references* -- that the two String variables refer to the same String *object* and that's not what you want. Instead use either the String `equals(...)` or its `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods which perform a *functional equality* test -- that the Strings have the same characters in the same order -- which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Also read up on the difference between assignment and relational equality. For a bonus read up on yoda expressions. Even though only a 3am debugging session permanently reinforces the difference.

Comment: Not sure what IDE you're using, but you should've gotten a big fat warning about doing assignment inside an if-condition. Ignoring those warnings is a surefire way to introduce bugs, especially as a beginner.

Comment: Okay, equalsIgnoreCase(...) works just fine. Im still a little bit confused about the "dont do assignment inside an if condition".

So through the way i did it im always setting my booleans true? Whats the best way to bypass that? 
btw im using Eclipse with 1.8 and im not getting any warnings regarding these issues

Answer (score 1):

in your if-statement you are setting animal to true every time `if (animal = true){`, instead of checking it (`==`)  .
Also, for Strings you must use `.equals()` instead of `==`.